# All over the place

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My beginning, reversed, indicates first place.

My middle is a US gov place.

My end is your place.

Where am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are

> Nowhere

My beginning, reversed, indicates first place.

> **Now** -  which, when reversed, is "won", past tense of win.

My middle is a US gov place.

> **WH** - acronym for the **W**hite **H**ouse.

My end is your place.

> **Here**

Comment: Overdue congratulations hexomino on the $\color{gold}{\huge\star}$ [tag:riddle] badge. The third gold tag badge on PSE!!!